# ABAP Initial value with VALUE operator in SQL statement

Tags: select, abap

I have the following SQL statement and was wondering if I could rewrite it using the `VALUE` operator to avoid the `DATA` statement at the beginning.

```
  DATA(lv_initial) = VALUE /scwm/guid_hu( ).
  SELECT * FROM /scwm/tu_dlv 
    WHERE lgnum     = @lv_lgnum
      AND top_hu    = @lv_initial
    INTO TABLE @DATA(lt).
```

I.e., I would like to have something like the following, which gives the error: "Field 'VALUE' unknown. [...]", unfortunately.

```
  SELECT * FROM /scwm/tu_dlv
    WHERE lgnum     = @lv_lgnum
      AND top_hu    = @VALUE #( )
   INTO TABLE @DATA(lt).
```

Is this possible? I want to get rid of the `DATA` statement because it can lead to bugs easily if the variable is reused.

I searched on Google and in the ABAP key word documentation, specifically for "SELECT", "VALUE, Operator" and "DATA, Operator", but to no avail.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, it depends on the target release. For [release 7.40](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_compare.htm), the right-hand side of the comparison needs to be (among other alternatives)

> a host variable or a literal

Whereas in [release 7.50](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_compare.htm), that has been replaced to allow for

> a literal, a host variable, or a host expression

That extension to [host expressions](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenopen_sql_host_expressions.htm) should allow you to do what you want to do, as shown [in this example](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenhost_expr_in_where_cond_abexa.htm).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately, I am currently working with release 7.40, but at least I can stop searching now.